# Knockout Js get value from Config

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, requirejs, knockout

I want to see if my module is enabled in config are through html using Knockout JS.

ko if: module_enabled ==1 show a button if not don't show a button
But i get this following error Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return module_enabled() }"
Message: module_enabled is not defined

Answer (score 1):

got the answer

```
 <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="additional" xsi:type="object">{module_name}\Model\AdditionalConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

```
/**
 * Retrieve assoc array of checkout configuration
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getConfig()
{
    return [
        'foo' => [
            'bar' => 'data',
        ],
    ];
}
```

this is the js file

```
 getSampleTotal: function () {;
                return window.checkoutConfig.foo.bar;
            }
```

html ko file

```
<p data-bind="html: getSampleTotal()"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to also do it directly on the HTML ko file:

```
<p data-bind="html: window.checkoutConfig.foo.bar"></p>
```

You can also use it as a condition to display data:

```
<!-- ko if: (checkoutConfig.customerData.foo.bar == 1)-->
<p data-bind="html: 'some text"></p>
<!-- /ko -->
```